# Kivy App loads with other colors than defaults every launch (bug)

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

(Python 3.7.3 / Kivy 1.10.1 / Win10 patch 1809)

Hi, thanks for taking some time to read me. I'm having an issue with Kivy loading my app's text with different colors than the default ones. The said text should be white (default color), but sometimes randomly appears grey, or almost black when I close then relaunch the app. I didn't have this issue yesterday, it has started to happen today.

Here are screenshots of different attempts to run `mytest.py`, I didn't do anything more than closing and relaunching the app :

1st attempt :
[image: 1st attempt]

2nd attempt :
[image: 2nd attempt]

3rd attempt : 
[image: 3rd attempt]

4th attempt :
[image: 4th attempt]

Also, some message got printed in the console when I launched my app :

```
ANOMALY: use of REX.w is meaningless (default operand size is 64)
```

I haven't tried anything to solve the problem except uninstalling/reinstalling Kivy via Pip because I don't know where to start first, I'm new to both Kivy and OpenGL (not to Python 3).

Here is `mytest.py` :

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

class MyGrid(Widget):
    button_1 = ObjectProperty(None)

    def print_erase_all_text(self, text_input:TextInput):
        if text_input.text:
            print(text_input.text)
        text_input.select_all()
        text_input.delete_selection()

class MyTestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyTestApp().run()
```

Then here is `mytest.kv` :

```
<MyGrid>
    textinput_1: textinput_1

    GridLayout:
        cols: 3
        size: root.width, root.height

        Label:
            text: "Text 1"

        TextInput:
            id: textinput_1
            multiline: False

        Button:
            text: "Print & erase"
            on_release:
                root.print_erase_all_text(textinput_1)

        Label:
            text: "Text 2"

        TextInput:
            multiline: False

        Button:
            text: "Do nothing"

        Label:
            text: "Text 3"

        TextInput:
            multiline: False

        Button:
            text: "Do nothing"
```

As you can see, I didn't change any color setting of any object in my code, so no text should appear in any other color than the default white.

I think that's all the info I have. If you need anything more just ask me and I'll do my best. Thanks again for reading me.

Comment: send this problem to [kivy page](https://kivy.org) or to its [issues tracker](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues)

Comment: I'll try this when I'll have some time for it, thank you. Any answer is still welcome.

Comment: This was a bug arising from using a new SDL2, it is fixed in Kivy master: https://github.com/kivy/kivy/pull/6312 and should be included in a new release shortly.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I got the zip file, where should I unzip the dlls ?

Comment: Ok I'm just dumb, I've downloaded Kivy 1.11.0, now let's see how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

## OS - Windows 10

### Uninstall Kivy & Dependencies

```
python -m pip uninstall kivy
python -m pip uninstall kivy.deps.sdl2
python -m pip uninstall kivy.deps.glew
python -m pip uninstall kivy.deps.gstreamer
```

### Installation

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools
python -m pip install kivy.deps.sdl2==0.1.18
python -m pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy.deps.glew
python -m pip install kivy.deps.gstreamer
python -m pip install kivy.deps.angle
python -m pip install kivy
```

### Verify SDL2 - 0.1.18

Check that *kivy.deps.sdl2* is version 0.1.18 i.e. folder name, ***kivy.deps.sdl2-0.1.18.dist-info***, in  `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages`. Replace *username* with your user-name.

Answer (score 0):

Got my answer thanks to inclement, installing this wheel below helped me to get rid of this bug. Thanks a lot !

Wheel for Python 3.7 64 bit : https://kivy.org/downloads/appveyor/kivy/Kivy-1.11.0.dev0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl

Other wheels : https://kivy.org/downloads/appveyor/kivy/

**EDIT :** Well, it worked for a moment, then the problem reappeared even with my original `mytest.py`, and I haven't done anything to Kivy's site-packages files after upgrading to Kivy 1.11.0.dev0. Is Kivy really suitable for developing stable apps or is it always that messy ? I really want it to work, Kivy looks interesting, but it doesn't look stable at all. 
I don't even know where to post now so I guess I'll edit this post until I get answers so I'll post answers afterwards.

**EDIT 2 :** Just a screenshot :

[image]

Comment: No problem running your app using Kivy 1.10.1, Python 3.7.3, Windows 10 Home, and kivy.deps.sdl2 v0.1.18. Downgrade kivy.deps.sdl2 to version 0.1.18. `python -m pip install kivy.deps.sdl2==0.1.18`

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me. I've just tried switching from Kivy 1.11.0 to 1.10.1 and installing sdl2 0.1.18 using your command but now Kivy can't find sdl2's DLL and I can't get a window. Screenshot of the result here : https://gyazo.com/d31bb3d7c76a2d6f12729f1a52ac415d

The error written in french means "The specified module can't be found."

Comment: Please try uninstall and re-install as in my post. Good luck.