# Python crashes whenever I run Kivy programme

Tags: python, kivy

wanted to try out kivy, so I installed it and followed the Pong game code on the kivy tutorial. However, every time I run the programme, it says "Python has stopped working".. Any ideas what may be the problem?

Tried using different versions of Python (3.7 and 2.7), but it always crashes whenever I run the code. I simply used the code provided in the Pong game tutorial on the kivy site:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

class PongGame(Widget):
    pass

class PongApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return PongGame()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    PongApp().run()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
When I run:

[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\HY\.kivy\logs\kivy_19-05-24_7.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.1
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.1 (default, Dec 10 2018, 22:54:23) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_gif (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <glew>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'4.5.0 - Build 22.20.16.4749'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Intel'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 5
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'4.50 - Build 22.20.16.4749'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
```

Comment: What is your OS? Please share Python's trace back and/or Kivy log.

Comment: I'm on Windows 10!

Comment: Running your app will display a blank or black window because there is nothing to display. Try replacing `Widget` with `Label` and `return PongGame()` with `return PongGame(text='Pong Game')`

Comment: @ikolim unfortunately, that doesn't work as well.The app itself starts with no problem, but as soon as it starts, there will also be a windows popup saying python has stopped..

Comment: Uninstall Python v3.7.1 and install v3.7.3.

Comment: I tried that as well, no luck... There is an error message that says an unhandled win32 exception occurred in python.exe..

Comment: Install *pypiwin32*, `python -m pip install pypiwin32`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it says the requirement is already satisfied :(

Comment: Check that *pypiwin32* is version 223 i.e. folder name, ***pypiwin32-223.dist-info***, in  `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages`. Replace *username* with your user-name.

Comment: Hello, I checked that and it seems I have both 223 and 224 inside the site-packages folder.. Could that be the problem?

Comment: The other one is ***pywin32-224.dist-info***. I have that one too but it is not the problem. Have you try [uninstall and re-install Kivy.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56208785/kivy-app-loads-with-other-colors-than-defaults-every-launch-bug/56300239#56300239)?

Comment: Yeah, have tried that too. The lack of a clear error message from the console and logs make it really difficult to pinpoint the problem.. Python runs fine as long as it does not run any kivy programme.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your
terminal:

```
pip install pipwin
```

then type this

```
pipwin install kivy
```